# Count records in mysql table as different columns depending on different values of a column

Tags: mysql, count

Please consider following sample table structure:

```
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| msisdn                        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| job_search_text               | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| local_job_region_id           | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
|   .......                     | .......      | ...  | ... | ....    | ....  |
|   .......                     | .......      | ...  | ... | ....    | ....  |
|   .......                     | .......      | ...  | ... | ....    | ....  |
|   .......                     | .......      | ...  | ... | ....    | ....  |
|   .......                     | .......      | ...  | ... | ....    | ....  |
|   .......                     | .......      | ...  | ... | ....    | ....  |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to count rows as follows:

```
If job_search_text='a' then count row as 'A'
Else If job_search_text='b' then count row as 'B'
Else If job_search_text='c' then count row as 'C'
.
.
.
Else count row as 'Other'
```

The query which I wrote is like:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN job_search_text='a' THEN 1 END) as 'A',COUNT(CASE WHEN job_search_text='b' THEN 1 END) as 'b' FROM subscriber
```

But this query compares job_search_text for every CASE, and also it does not handle the Else case mentioned above. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, but change count to SUM( IF( ))... something like

```
select
      sum( if( s.job_search_text = 'a', 1, 0 ) ) as 'A',
      sum( if( s.job_search_text = 'b', 1, 0 ) ) as 'B',
      sum( if( s.job_search_text = 'c', 1, 0 ) ) as 'C',
      sum( if( s.job_search_text = 'd', 1, 0 ) ) as 'D',
      sum( if( s.job_search_text = 'e', 1, 0 ) ) as 'E',
      sum( if( s.job_search_text IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ), 0, 1 ) ) as 'Other'
   from 
      subscriber s
```

The "IN" test for the other, if it FINDs something already accounted for, then it's summing a zero value.  If it CANT find one of the a-e entries, it sums the ONE for you "Other" count.

Comment: Thats elegant. It solves my problem. But can I optimize this by using if,else if,else architecture? Otherwise I am using this

Comment: @djaqeel, Sorry, you can't optimize it... every record will be hit only one time, but fall into only one "slot" so you get one final row of all records in a columnar format.  If you don't care about column output, then doing the option by xQbert with the group by is your option.  This type of query is still very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), job_Search_Text
FROM table
group by job_Search_text
```

Returns 1 row per job_Search_Text and the count so like...  There would be no "other"

```
10 A
15 B
25 C
30 D
50 E
99 F
```