# SQL nested query possible?

Tags: sql, nested

I have found select statements that basically use different where clauses to count. My question is, how do I combine the results in one statement so that these counts can become columns?

1. select count(*) as c1 from table1 where city = 'nyc'
2. select count(*) as c2 from table1 where city = 'boston'
3. select count(*) as c3 from table1 where city = 'sf'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count records in mysql table as different columns depending on different values of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8788133/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN city = 'nyc' THEN 1 END) AS Nyc,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN city = 'boston' THEN 1 END) AS Boston,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN city = 'sf' THEN 1 END) AS Sf
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. What if the where statement has multiple conditions, like city='nyc' and gender = 'male'?

Comment: If you have multiple conditions, you are better off using row based results and group by.

Comment: @Yang If you have multiple conditions, you can just add them into your `case`... `WHEN city = 'nyc' AND gender = 'male' THEN 1 END) AS nycMale`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sum()` and also `filtering only required cities`

```
select sum(case when city = 'nyc' then 1 end) c1,
       sum(case when city = 'boston' then 1 end) c2,
       sum(case when city = 'sf' then 1 end) c3
from table1
where city in ('nyc','boston','sf')
```

Comment: No problem, you can add more conditions to the case like, (case when city='nyc' and gender = 'male' then 1 end) etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(CASE WHEN city = 'nyc' THEN 1 END) as c1,
       count(CASE WHEN city = 'boston' THEN 1 END) as c2,       
       count(CASE WHEN city = 'sf' THEN 1 END) as c3
from table1
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5a87/1)

Also in SQLServer2005+, Oracle you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operation

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
PIVOT (
COUNT(city) FOR city IN ([nyc], [boston], [sf])
) p
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5a87/2)

Comment: The pivot works pretty much the same in Oracle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05497/13)

Comment: @Conrad Frix Thanks for the clarifications and demo!

Answer (score 2):

You can give GROUP BY a chance,

```
SELECT city, gender, count(*)
WHERE gender = "male"
GROUP BY city, gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

for completeness)

```
select
    (select count(*) as c1 from table1 where city = 'nyc') as c1,
    (select count(*) as c2 from table1 where city = 'boston') as c2,
    (select count(*) as c3 from table1 where city = 'sf') as c3
```